# MyBatis and SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, mybatis

I want to insert data using MyBatis insert statement.

I have two tables `empl_user` and `empl_user_group`.

I want to insert value of first_name,Last_name,Email_address in empl_user and I want to insert brand_data in empl_user_group.

I want to do this using one insert query. Is this possible?

There is a column name `User_Id` which is common in both the tables.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL server

Comment: In standart SQL - no. Even if it was possible is not advisable. Write two sqparete sentences and execute (you a re using mybatis).

Comment: thanks but what are the disadvantages, I mean why it is not advisable..?

Comment: And if we face the same scenario in normal SQL database then will it be fine..?

Comment: Why not two Insert statements in Transactional way?